# App crashed when update

Tags: ios, crash

I archive my app in xcode7.3,and no clean, but it success and the apple pass.But when I update my app form the AppStore, it crash and I am nervous.
So,I begin find the problem and I failed.

Below are some strange things.
it crash in iPhone6p,ios9.2 after update;it not crash and run perfect in **iPhone5s,ios 9.1;**
other, I provide the crash log in picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5uWw.jpg)

How can i do it Please help

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know whether you submitted your app in appstore or you wanna submit?

Comment: I have submitted my app,it's all 3 version,and my database is RealmSwift.The problem crash happen between the 2 and 3.

Comment: please be clear..whether your app is in appstore or while you submitting its getting error?when you get this crash log?while running the app or while submitting the app to app store?

Comment: OK.my app version 1.0.1 is in appstore.when I complete the version 1.0.2,I submitting it to appstore and it go well.When it is issue by apple,I update my app to 1.0.2 from appstore.unlucky,it crashed.then I connect my iphone with my iMac.through xcode,I find the crash log producted by my iphone,and i have show the crash log in picture. you can view it.

Comment: Cool.so you go any other details other than crash log?please put a breakpoint and let me know where you get a crash?

Comment: otherway,I just do such a test.I find the 2 (A,B) iphone which have the version1.0.1 of my app。I run the version 1.0.2 through xcode-debug in A,it ok;but when I run the version 1.0.2 through xcode-release in B,it crash.so,is it the problem between debug and release??

Comment: Ok so the app crashes when you initialize the path for realm?Which version you are using in Realm?Try to update a version of realm

Comment: You are showing a method.can you post a full method with coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohohoh,I final understand the problem with a friend help.It is the Realm's Bug.I used the realm 0.96.3 in my app old version,so the crash would happen when you  update your realmshame.when I update realm to 0.98.8,the crash not happen in all my test.so,I guess it is the Realm's bug,and in the lasted version,realm has solve the bug.anyway,my problem is done.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on software issues and there is no clear solution to this kind of problem,but it can be sorted out,please verify below links where you can detect the solution of your problem.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6755076?start=0&tstart=0

My solution:
Try to remove the content of ~/Library/Caches, /Library/Caches and /System/Library/Caches